# Why am I getting error 500 on Azure Aspn.net Web API?

Tags: asp.net, node.js, azure, deployment

I get this error only when I try to do a post/put request from another server (node js / $http), but I'm able to consume the api with get requests.

In addition if I try in the same node js web app from client side (angular.js) I can do get, post, put, delete requests perfectly, using apps like postman as well. So, why do I get error 500 only when I try to post/put with the node.js $http library? Even I copied the exact request params and pasted it to postman and it worked.

You can see the error below. I copied that from azure logs.

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error 
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred. 
Most likely causes:
IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred. IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

Things you can try:
Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.Verify the permissions for the DLL. 
Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439">here</a>. </li> </ul> 

Detailed Error Information:

> Module ManagedPipelineHandler Notification ExecuteRequestHandler 
> Handler System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler Error Code
> 0x00000000
```

Comment: Here is a thread with the same error message, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/36814998-7c42-4a9e-b738-5addec5fd9f3/azure-website-throwing-error-when-logged-into-the-website-but-not-in-log-off-state?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview, can you have a try on this solution? Any update, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT i had set 'customError mode="Off" ' already.